# If statement in select (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, if-statement, oracle10g

Hi I have simply select and works great:

```
select 'CARAT Issue Open' issue_comment, i.issue_id, i.issue_status, i.issue_title, i.ISSUE_summary ,i.issue_description, i.severity,
gcrs.Area_name, gcrs.sector_name,

substr(gcrs.stream_name,1,case when instr(gcrs.stream_name,' (')=0 then 100 else instr(gcrs.stream_name,' (')-1 end) ISSUE_DIVISION,

case when gcrs.STREAM_NAME like 'NON-GT%' THEN 'NON-GT' ELSE gcrs.STREAM_NAME END as ISSUE_DIVISION_2


from table(f_carat_issues_as_of('31/MAR/2013')) i
inner join v_gcrs_with_stream gcrs on i.segment_id = gcrs.segment_id

where UPPER(ISSUE_STATUS) like '%OPEN%'
```

Now I want to call two columns:
ISSUE_DIVISION and ISSUE_DIVISION_2

if they are equal in new columns should be value 1 if are not equal should be 0,

how can I do it ?

---

my full code:

```
select 'CARAT Issue Open' issue_comment, i.issue_id, i.issue_status, i.issue_title, i.ISSUE_summary ,i.issue_description, i.severity,
gcrs.Area_name, gcrs.sector_name,

substr(gcrs.stream_name,1,case when instr(gcrs.stream_name,' (')=0 then 100 else instr(gcrs.stream_name,' (')-1 end) ISSUE_DIVISION,

case when gcrs.STREAM_NAME like 'NON-GT%' THEN 'NON-GT' ELSE gcrs.STREAM_NAME END as ISSUE_DIVISION_2


from table(f_carat_issues_as_of('31/MAR/2013')) i
inner join v_gcrs_with_stream gcrs on i.segment_id = gcrs.segment_id

where UPPER(ISSUE_STATUS) like '%OPEN%' and 

CASE WHEN ISSUE_DIVISION = ISSUE_DIVISION_2 THEN 
     CASE WHEN  ISSUE_DIVISION is null then "Null Value found"
     Else 1 End
ELSE 0 END As Issue_Division_Result
```

but I get error on line:
    ELSE 0 END As Issue_Division_Result

ORA-00920: invalid relational operator :(

Comment: This won't properly handle NULL values for GCRS.STREAM_NAME, since INSTR() returns NULL in that case.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ISSUE_DIVISION = ISSUE_DIVISION_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISSUES
    --  <add any columns to outer select from inner query> 
  FROM
 (  -- your query here --
   select 'CARAT Issue Open' issue_comment, ...., ..., 
          substr(gcrs.stream_name,1,case when instr(gcrs.stream_name,' (')=0 then 100 else  instr(gcrs.stream_name,' (')-1 end) ISSUE_DIVISION,
          case when gcrs.STREAM_NAME like 'NON-GT%' THEN 'NON-GT' ELSE gcrs.STREAM_NAME END as ISSUE_DIVISION_2
     from ....
    where UPPER(ISSUE_STATUS) like '%OPEN%'
 )
 WHERE... -- optional --
```

Comment: This just saved my marriage.  Thanks.

Comment: sometimes PL/SQL tries to destroy anyone marriage ! ha ha ha

Answer (score 16):

So simple you can use **case** statement here.

```
CASE WHEN ISSUE_DIVISION = ISSUE_DIVISION_2 THEN 
         CASE WHEN  ISSUE_DIVISION is null then "Null Value found" //give your option
         Else 1 End
ELSE 0 END As Issue_Division_Result
```

Comment: This will return 0 if both values are null which might not be what the OP expects / wants (see my comment on the OP).

Answer (score 4):

In one line, answer is as below;

[ CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'VALUE' THEN 'SHOW_THIS' ELSE 'SHOW_OTHER' END as ALIAS ]

Answer (score 0):

use the variable, Oracle does not support SQL in that context without an INTO. With a properly named variable your code will be more legible anyway.